# Give custom name to a process started with nohup

Tags: bash, shell

When I create new process using `exec` I can give it some custom name using `-a` option, i.e. `exec -a MyName MyCommand`

Doing so facilities handling bunch of same processes started with different parameters. For instance if I have following:

```
exec -a MyName1 MyCommand param1
exec -a MyName2 MyCommand param2
```

and for some reason I want to kill a latter it's as simple as:
`pkill -f MyName2`.

Problem is I don't know how to achieve same effect with processes started using `nohup`. I've read about `-p` option, but it's not always supported.
`disjoin` doesn't seem to work either.

Has anybody faced similar problem?

Comment: nohup does nothing you can't do yourself with only shell built-ins. You don't need it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash's `exec` command has a `-a NAME` option for this:

```
nohup bash -c 'exec -a xxx sleep 12345'
```

---

According to `help exec`:

```
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [argument ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
    any redirections take effect in the current shell.

    Options:
      -a name   pass NAME as the zeroth argument to COMMAND
      -c        execute COMMAND with an empty environment
      -l        place a dash in the zeroth argument to COMMAND

    If the command cannot be executed, a non-interactive shell exits, unless
    the shell option `execfail' is set.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless COMMAND is not found or a redirection error occurs.
```

Comment: Thanks. I did quick check and above seems to do what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `nohup` in the first place; it does nothing the shell can't do on its own.

```
exec -a MyName1 MyCommand param1 >nohup.out 2>&1 </dev/null & disown -h "$!"
exec -a MyName2 MyCommand param2 >nohup.out 2>&1 </dev/null & disown -h "$!"
```

Most of what nohup does is just redirections. The rest is identical to `disown -h` (which tells the shell not to forward HUP signals to that process).

Of course, you could also choose a distinct file to store each command's logs, and store the PIDs in variables -- doing the latter will prevent you from needing to use `pgrep` at all.